# American Equivalent of "Bog Standard"

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, synonyms, british-english, idiom-requests

I'm searching for an American English phrase that is the most readily equivalent to the British expression ***bog standard*** (which means, as I understand, *plain, ordinary or unremarkable*).

I'm tempted to use ***run of the mill*** or ***out of the box*** but these don't really have quite the same flavor as *bog standard*.

No need for an etymology lesson, here. But I would appreciate any synonymous phrasings, especially for those with a bit more humorous flair.

**Edit:**

For to provide context as to assist I present the usage:

> My ***bog standard*** stepmother, Rose, in her inaugural summer as my de facto parent made it known with little uncertainty that the absolute last thing she wanted while school was out of session was for me to be within 50 miles of her teenage daughter.

In this case I'm intending *bog standard* to mean something of standard issue; I'm trying to say that my stepmother is a stereotypical archetype. I like *bog standard* but I am afraid that a wider American audience will be unfamiliar with the phrase.

**Edit #2:**

For to clarify in a manner that furthers understanding:

There are a lot of phrases on both sides of the Atlantic that mean plain, boring, unexciting, standard or average. But *bog standard* has a special flavor all its own. It has this special, subtle knock to it.

To sort-of clarify the matter so you know what I want, I want the reader in just one or two (or three) words get the feeling that she is a straight from The Brothers Grimm standard issue stepmother. She might as well have come stock from the Acme Stepmother Factory in a wooden crate marked "Contents: One Stepmother. Fragile. This Side Up." I want it to be like I'm standing in line being handed the contents of my life: One childhood, pleasant, check; One adolescence, awkward, check; One stepmother, standard issue, check. I want one small phrase that captures this whole concept, packs it in a nice little box, puts a nice little bow on it and then hands it to the reader.

That's not too much to ask, is it?

Comment: What’s wrong with “bog standard”? I certainly use it, and I’m  American.

Comment: @tchrist: nothing's wrong with using it in America as an American except no one would recognize it and they'd look at you funny.

Comment: "Bog standard stepmother" sounds a bit strange to me.

Comment: @Mitch I get the idea you worry about that sort of thing a great deal more than I do.

Comment: @tchrist being looked at funny or being understood? ;)

Comment: I'm American.  I (and the friends I just asked) have never heard of "Bog Standard," so I don't think you're being overly-cautious...

Comment: What Hugo said. Speaking as a Brit, I probably use and/or hear "bog standard" on a weekly basis, but we don't normally use it to describe people. The sense is of *basic, not having any optional extras or enhancements*, rather than OP's supposed "stereotypical archetype*.

Comment: I also use and understand "bog standard" as an American. I think that @Mitch is making false assumptions about the term's currency in America.

Comment: So far in America, SomeNorCalGuy, tchrist, and JSBangs understand the term; while Mitch, BlueRaja, and at least four other people who upvoted their comments, myself included, do not know it. @SomeNorCalGuy, write from experience (noting Hugo's and FumbleFingers's comments about usage) and let the half of America that doesn't know the idiom unleash their Google-fu.

Comment: @zleptan: The questionable Google nGrams evidence show that in print both British and American have no instances before 1970 rising to a max at the end, with the max frequency for [British 0.45E-6](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bog+standard&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3), and for [American 0.26E-7](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bog+standard&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3), 20 times more in British writing. But that doesn't mean it's unheard of in the US (though it is to me). Does it feel that recent in England?

Comment: @FumbleFingers See the article I reference in my answer to this question.

Comment: "stock standard" is commonly used in Australia to mean the same thing, but my searching shows that it's not often used elsewhere.

Comment: @Mitch, I'm not quite sure I understand what you're saying. I wasn't arguing with how well it's understood in the US; I only noted that roughly half of those Americans here know the term, and said that OP should just use it if he thinks it fits his context. [Aside—my handle is zpletan, not zleptan. I don't mind except that I don't get pinged on addresses to zleptan.]

Comment: Huh, it's surprising some US'ers have not heard it. One man's vote, for me, it's common in the US.

Comment: Just another suggestion Jed, you hear "Mark 1..." being used (it's rather sort of military ... as in say "mark 1 eyeball.." .. just google if not familiar).

Comment: By the way, **in your actual sentence", "standard-issue stepmother!" is the perfect phrase.  Look no further.

Comment: Curious -- I've always assumed that "bog standard" was a bog standard US idiom.  I certainly use the term from time to time, and I've never had anyone act like it "threw" them.

Comment: I've lived in the US all my life, and "bog standard" seems perfectly "normal" to me.  To my recollection the term became "normal" about 1965.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Other common phrases/expressions that could be close:

- cookie cutter
- standard issue
- factory standard
- off-the-shelf
- run of the mill
- quintessential (she is the quintessential step-mother)
- classic (she's your classic step-mother type)
- stereotypical

Or you can branch out from synonyms to other ideas that convey more or less the same sentiment. Something like "right out of Grimms Brothers," depending on what you're ultimately going for.

Best of luck!

Comment: Yes, +1 for quintessential. It works well in the OP's sentence.

Comment: None of those is negative, though.

Comment: The OP didn't say he wanted negativity in the term itself, only that it mean something like 'stereotypical archetype.' The humorous, negative implication is carried by the term 'stepmother' when paired with one of the above words.

Many of these other answers seem to be emphasizing plainness or negativity rather than the idea of someone being an archetypal example of something.

Comment: I like *cookie cutter*.  I think it has just the same slightly negative tinge as *bog standard*.

Comment: Provided my parameters, I think this best addresses the core of question: How to replace *bog standard* with a better, more easily understood American English phrase. I'm still debating using *quintessential* versus an extended Brothers Grimm comparison, though. And for all you *bog standard* fans, I'm still going to use it, just somewhere else in my story. Let the readers Google it, if they have to.

Comment: "standard issue" is good, echoing "standard" in "bog standard", and there's also a bit of wordplay with "issue" (offspring) and it also conveys the idea that the narrator really has no say in the matter but is "issued" a step-mother. You get what you get.

Answer (score 20):

*[Garden variety](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/garden_variety)* and *standard issue* are possibilities.  *[Stereotypical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stereotypical)* has an applicable sense but its usual sense of "banal, commonplace and clichéd because of overuse" gets in the way.

Comment: "Common or garden [thing]"

Comment: *Garden varietal*, maybe? *My **garden varietal** stepmother...*

Comment: @SomeNorCalGuy, I don't know how "correct" it is, but I'd simply say, "My garden variety stepmother."

Comment: @SomeNorCalGuy No, you would just *garden-variety* as an adjective.  I don’t really like it with a stepmother, though.

Comment: @tchrist, I've upvoted cornbread's *archetypal*, which I think is a good word to answer the question as asked, although *draconian* or *Victorian* probably would work to better effect in the example sentence.

Comment: The problem is that *garden-variety* and *standard-issue* don’t have the added dismissive or derogatory tone that *bog-standard* does. See my own answer for details.

Comment: Garden-variety is somewhat dismissive, in an US context at least.  If it were nice, you'd keep it inside.

Answer (score 16):

Would *[textbook](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/textbook?show=1&t=1335653313)* or *[archetypal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archetypal)* do?

Comment: Oooooh! *Textbook* is officially under consideration now.

Comment: No, those aren’t negative, so they won’t work.

Comment: OP never states an intent to be negative.

Comment: I think 'archetypal' is a better phrase when referring to *people*. It can have a negative connotation if the archetype itself is negative.

Answer (score 15):

"Vanilla" sounds like it could work.

Comment: +1: Yes,  and you can say  "*plain vanilla*" as well.  And if you can rephrase to include mention of the item you can say, "*plain old X*" as well.

Comment: I resent the use of *vanilla* to mean *plain*. It’s a rich, complex, and beautiful flavour, the 1970s be damned.

Comment: @JonPurdy Indeed, vanilla is the most complex flavor known to man.  It has something like 250+ flavor components.  Chocolate has fewer than half that count.

Comment: @JonPurdy: I agree ~ maybe it's just the color? I believe the term came to mean "plain" based on ice cream shoppes; unfortunately, too many ice cream makers don't use enough real vanilla to flavor their vanilla ice cream – if they use any at all.

Comment: Vanilla doesn't have the sort of threatening connotation that the OP is going for, does it? My vanilla stepmother... I think of someone who is vanilla as being mild-mannered or ordinary.

Comment: *Vanilla* sounds like the answer, if *bog standard* means, as is said in a comment above by @FumbleFingers, *basic, not having any optional extras or enhancements*.

Answer (score 7):

One possibility would be to describe the stepmother as *classic*. In one sense, the word means outstanding in some way, but it is often used to mean:

> Of a well-known type; typical

<sup>[Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/classic)</sup>

Comment: But *classic* has a positive connotation, while *bog-standard* has a negative one.  See my answer.

Comment: @tchrist, I think paired with stepmother -- classic stepmother -- it would wouldn't have a positive connotation.

Answer (score 4):

[This article](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-bog1.htm) may be interesting.  It says, amongst other things:

> *Bog-standard* is a well-known informal term, which originated in Britain; it means something ordinary or basic, but often in a dismissive or derogatory way.

The problem with all the quasi-synonyms people keep giving here is that they all lack the dismissive/derogatory aspect that *bog-standard* conveys. That’s why I use it myself, because I don’t know a true synonym.

I suppose in some contexts, *pedestrian* might work. Another possibility is *white-bread*, meaning something that is boringly bland, uninspiring, insipid. Sometimes *strait-laced* may work, too.

But these all seem less useful than plain ol’ *bog-standard* for something so super-ordinary as to be unremarkable in the extreme, with a dismissive but not quite sneering undertone. As the cited article says, it may have originated in Britain, but its use is not and shouldn’t be limited to there.  It’s a good word, one that  won’t risk the racial connotations that *white-bread* may summon up.

Comment: I think this is helpful in showing that bog-standard probably isn't the ideal term the OP wants regardless of whether Brits or Americans are in the audience as he doesn't seem to be placing importance on the negative connotation. His favorite alternative so far seems to be 'textbook' which also doesn't carry any negative connotation.

Comment: @CharlesW I do want that subtle knock that 'bog standard' has. There are lots of phrases on both sides of the Atlantic that mean plain, boring, unexciting, standard or average. But *bog standard* has a special flavor all it's own. I want the reader in just one or two words get the feeling that she is a straight from The Brothers Grimm standard issue stepmother. She might as well have come stock from the Acme Stepmother Factory in a wooden crate marked "Contents: One Stepmother. This Side Up". -OP

Comment: @SomeNorCalGuy I don't see any inkling of something being archetypal in the provided definition for 'bog-standard.' It seems just to mean so plain as to be bad, typical of a bog's level of interest.

From context, I gather that you want to communicate is, 'this lady is a dead-on-ringer for whatever bad ideas are typically associated with stepmothers.'

If so, then that doesn't really entail anything about her being plain, hum-drum, or boring -- just that she's 'one of those ones.'

Am I off here? I think clarifying this will help.

Comment: @SomeNorCalGuy, then perhaps the words you want are simply *evil stepmother*—any American, I'd say, will instantly know what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm one of those Americans who knows what *bog standard* means, but I think in the OP's context, something like "standard issue" or "garden variety" would work better, because "bog standard" really doesn't apply to people.

Answer (score 3):

Update: Per OP's comment on tchrist's answer (reproduced below), the term I now suggest is **evil stepmother**.

> @CharlesW I do want that subtle knock that 'bog standard' has. There are lots of phrases on both sides of the Atlantic that mean plain, boring, unexciting, standard or average. But bog standard has a special flavor all it's own. I want the reader in just one or two words get the feeling that she is a straight from The Brothers Grimm standard issue stepmother. She might as well have come stock from the Acme Stepmother Factory in a wooden crate marked "Contents: One Stepmother. This Side Up". -OP

---

My original suggestion doesn't have much of a negative connotation, and what negativity it has refers to attractiveness. Notwithstanding, I and three others at the time of this edit thought it was a decent answer to what we thought OP was asking, so I leave it in.

Original answer:

> How about *plain jane*?
>
> > simple and modest; unadorned; basic: *a plain-Jane car dressed up with leather upholstery* (Random House Dictionary, via Dictionary.com).

Comment: Not much negative connotation there.

Comment: True (though I didn't originally know that *bog standard* carried a negative one). Additionally, what negative connotation it bears relates to attractiveness. I'll edit that in for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 1):

An American idiom that has a fairly similar meaning is *bone stock*. (See [this answer](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54927/why-do-people-use-bone-in-the-phrase-bone-stock-to-emphasize-that-a-car-is-u&ei=DWucT761F4iXiQLL7ZGCAQ&usg=AFQjCNEZpv_O8xmLzFKiLeB7JrGl4y-IZg&sig2=yG6rAbHv1QdxkKox-Zb1DA).)

Comment: I'm American and having lived in New York, Massachusetts, California, and Arizona, I've never even heard this "idiom"

Comment: Never heard of *bone stock* before in my long life.

Comment: Apparently, there's a shortage of car guys/gals on EL&U.

Comment: @tchrist: Well, you have now. Thank goodness for longevity.

Comment: @Gnawme the 43 Chevy Split Window pickup being hot-roded in my garage disagrees with you.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Just to show that there are no hard feelings, I upvoted your Chevy's last answer.

Comment: @Gnawme Maybe that will lessen the loneliness it feels sitting in the garage. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I find *stepmother* an unnecessary diversion.

> My stepmother, very like women of her time, ...

That would go much better with the context.

Comment: I think *stepmother* is a lot worse than "unnecessary" - it effectively makes the question unanswerable. I see no possible way to associate the connotations of *bog-standard* with *stepmother*. If we go with OP's "stereotypical", that can surely only mean *à la Brothers Grimm*, which means nothing in relation to guarding her blood daughter's chastity from a stepson's attentions. So *typical of her time* (or *social class*, perhaps) is about all you could identify that might make her care more about such matters (it still seems a silly question to me though).

Comment: The question that begs attention here is, who the author suggests the attitude is typical of: stepmothers, or mothers in general, of the time? I think one being a stepmother is not really relevant.

Comment: It seems relevant to me if the speaker in the excerpt fancies his stepmother's daughter.

Comment: @cornbread ninja: Okay - so maybe the speaker fancies his stepsister, and his stepmother knows this. In which case one might well expect she'd want them kept apart, but to say she's therefore *bog-standard* (or stereoptypical, or whatever) sounds really weird to me). Surely any other attitude *apart from* wanting them kept apart would be would be "weird"? Woody Allen excepted, most people consider sexual congress with "step-relatives" to be a form of incest - universally reviled in all human societies we know of.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I agreed with your point the first time.  I was trying to defend the label of 'stepmother' as potentially important depending on the context and the writer's intent.  As for other motives, perhaps the speaker is simply a bad influence.

Comment: It seems like something of a stretch application of mother-in-law jokes. If I had to guess at a stereotype of stepmothers as compared to other types of mothers it would be that there may be additional tension or distance or even resentment in the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

> My *standard-issue* stepmother

is also possible.